# how to make mapping function work if the incoming request has less fields than expected

Tags: scala, playframework

I am experimenting with play/scala. I have following two case classes and I want to map data from form into this model

```
case class User (
  name:String,
  age:Int,
  female:Boolean,
  address:Address
)

case class Address (
                   fullStreet:String,
                   county:String,
                   country:String
                   )
```

In controller class, I have following mapping function and action defined

```
  val userForm = Form((mapping("name"->text,
    "age"->number,
    "female"->boolean,
    "address"->mapping("fullStreet"->text,
                        "county"->text,
                        "country"->text)(Address.apply)(Address.unapply)
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)))

  def post = Action { implicit request =>

    val u:Form[User] = userForm.bindFromRequest
    Ok(views.html.dataIndex(u))
  }
```

I am facing the following issue: To make the complete code work, I have to create a form which contains all the fields required in mapping as follows:

```
 <h1>Feed User Data</h1>
            @helper.form(action=routes.Data.post){
            @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
            @helper.inputText(userForm("age"))
            @helper.checkbox(userForm("female"))
            <fieldset>
            @helper.inputText(userForm("address.fullStreet"),'_label -> "Full Street")
            @helper.inputText(userForm("address.county"),'_label -> "County")
            @helper.select(userForm("address.country"),Seq(""->"---",
                                                        "United Kingdom"->"UK",
                                                        "France"->"FR") )
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit"/>
            }
```

If I create a form with say only input field for name, then bindFromRequest returns None instead of mapping only name field. Is there a way in which the form can contain less fields than required in mapping. I am not talking about fields in form with empty/optional values. I do not want to put the fields in the form at all.

Answer (score 2):

I usually create a case class that represents the form data (probably not all the info from the domain class), and in the controller/service I create the domain entity using my own rules (for instance, a default value for a field not represented on the form)

Comment: note: I would also like to know if anyone does it in a different way :) but until now I don't have any complex form